# Create an array with every row who contains a particular string from a CSV file

Tags: php, arrays, string, csv

I have this code that stores each line of a csv file into an array:

```
$tname = myfile.csv

if ($type == 'text/csv'){
           $csvData = file_get_contents($tname);
           $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
           $array = array();
              foreach ($lines as $line){
                      $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
                      echo $line."<br>";
               }
}
```

How can I store only the entire rows who contains "John is great!" string and discard the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) OR [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function.

```
if (strpos($line, 'John is great!') !== false) {
   echo 'true';
}
```

OR

```
if (preg_match('/John is great!/i',$line)) // i for case insensitive
    echo 'true';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tname = myfile.csv

if ($type == 'text/csv'){
    $csvData = file_get_contents($tname);
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
    $array = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line){
        if (stripos($line, 'John is great!') !== false) { 
            $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
             echo $line."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

I am assuming that you want a case insensitive match